# Select multiple columns from one alias

Tags: mysql, join, aliases

In my schema, there are two tables with the same column names (Changing them is not an option)

Performing a query with
`select * from tabA join tabB` results in a mysql error of 'Duplicate column name col'

The only solution to this is to select using aliases, however I do not want to type alias.col for every column (since I need all columns from both tables)

Is it possible to do something along the lines of:

```
select tabA.(colA, colB, colC...), tabB.(colA, colB, colC...)
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/115770/1

Comment: Thanks juergen but they aren't guaranteed to have equal PKs.

Comment: I was only refering to the fact that having the same columns does not necesarily lead to an *duplicate column* error.

Comment: I should have been clearer on what kind of query i'm trying to get working. I need a sum of two to several columns from many tables (each with similar pks, various other duplicate colums) Here is my problem exactly duplicated http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/115770/7

Answer (score 1):

no its not possible.

you have to do like that

```
  select tabA.colA, tabA.colB, tabA.colC..., tabB.colA,  tabB.colB,  tabB.colC...
```

if you have same name column in both tables , just give it an other alias like that.

lets say you have id column name in both tables.

```
 select tabA.id , tabB.id as id_B
```

will give you result

```
  id   id_B
```

Linger's [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fa835/9/1)

Comment: @Linger yes i have said it .